# Assert is function not passed in parameter is called

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-mock

Let's say I have a function like that:

```
def foo():
  bar()
```

Is there any way I could test if `bar` is called, when I'm not passing bar as parameter? My team use Python 3.6 and 3.5

Comment: You could probably modify [these function call counting decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Counting_function_calls) to suit your purpose.

Comment: There are a number of alternatives, depending on your exact needs - search ```python decorator function logging```.  Try one out and come back with questions about it if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) for that:

```
@patch('path.to.bar')
def test_foo(self, mock_bar):
    foo() 
    self.assertTrue(mock_bar.called)
```

You can also test with which values the function was called like this:

```
mock_bar.assert_called_with('some_param')
```

Hope it helps.